# nscd (DNS cache) is keep crashing

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system

I have the "nscd" service running to cache some DNS on the server.

You can say that my server is using it with heavy load.. but nothing insane.

Unfortunately, it's keep crashing.. (after a few minutes).

when i run it with: `nscd  --debug`, it's running for some time and then it's stops.

His last words was :

`nscd: cache.c:416: prune_cache: Assertion "dh->usable" failed.
Aborted (core dumped)`.

And then he died (well, the status was down, but it was still up, so iv'e killed it, and then started it up again)

I have tried to delete / clear the cache, but no luck.

I've searched for this issue, and i couldn't find solid evidence for the crash.

Comment: I just want to say that for now, the solution for me was with bind9... http://askubuntu.com/questions/22750/best-way-to-set-up-dns-caching